# Unable to render local svgs using Rollup.js plugin/Package using React,Fabric.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, fabricjs, rollupjs

Hi i am creating a local package using react and rollup.js . So in this react app im using a bunch of svgs. In the src i created a folder called assets in that i placed various svgs.
and need to display in the fabric canvas.

i used https://react-svgr.com/ also but i unable to render the svgs  in the canvas and the error is **url.replace is not a function at object.loadsvgfromurl**.

Below is my code

```
import c1 from "../../icons/c1.svg";
import c2 from "../../icons/c2.svg";
import c3 from "../../icons/c3.svg";
import c4 from "../../icons/c4.svg";
```

and i am creating an array

```
const addingIcons = [
            c1,
            c2,
            c3,
            c4
        ]
```

i have some method where i am doing this

```
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                if ((type === "data" || type === "json"))
                    continue;
                var tx, ty

                fabric.loadSVGFromURL(addingIcons[i], (objects, options) => {
                    icon = fabric.util.groupSVGElements(objects, options);
                    if (i == 0) {
                        tx = x + 8
                        ty = y + 8
                        icon.scaleToHeight(48)
                    }
                    else {

                        tx = x + shape.width + 16
                        icon.scaleToHeight(12)
                        if (text1.text.split('\n').length == 3)
                            ty = y + 10 + (i - 1) * text1.height / 3
                        else {
                            ty = y + 2 + (i - 1) * text1.height / 2
                            if (i === 1) icon.set('opacity', 0);
                        }

                    }

                    icon.set({ left: tx, top: ty });
                    group.addWithUpdate(icon)
                    canvas.renderAll();
                });
            }
```

below is my rollup.config.js code

```
import resolve from 'rollup-plugin-node-resolve';
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import commonjs from 'rollup-plugin-commonjs';
import generatePackageJson from 'rollup-plugin-generate-package-json'

import postcss from 'rollup-plugin-postcss';
import terser from '@rollup/plugin-terser';
import svgr from '@svgr/rollup'

export default {
    input: 'src/index.jsx',
    output: {
        file: 'dist/bundles/bundle.js',
        format: 'cjs'
    },
    plugins: [
        resolve({ extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.tsx','.css'] }),
        svgr(),
        commonjs({
            exclude: 'src/**',
          }),
        babel({
            extensions: ['.jsx', '.js', '.tsx'], 
            exclude: 'node_modules/**',
            presets: [
                // ...
                ["@babel/preset-react", { runtime: "automatic" }],
            ]
        }),
        postcss(
            {
                modules: false, // Disables class modification by default
    autoModules: true,
                extract: true,
                extensions: [".css"],
            }
        ),
        terser(),
        generatePackageJson({
            outputFolder: 'dist',
            baseContents: (pkg) => ({
                name: pkg.name,
                main: 'bundles/bundle.js',
                peerDependencies: {
                  "react": "^18.2.0"
                }
            })            
        })
    ], external: [
        'react',
        'react-dom',
         'fabric'
    ],
};
```